# Ethereum Address genration gives new address and new private key everytime in Android

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

I am using **'org.ethereum:geth:1.6.5'** dependency.
I am trying to follow github code of
https://github.com/ethmobile/ethdroid .I found it gives every time new private and address.
I want to have same private key and address when user add same phrase or seed in any device.It should create same wallet based on same phrase (or passowrd).

I tried to create **ECKey** by adding same SecureRandom object and Provider object everytime.Yet it gives new private key.
Is there any way to fullfil this requirements?

My code is:

```
           String TAG = "MainActivity >";
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    TextView tv;
    Provider provider =  SpongyCastleProvider.getInstance();
    MainActivity activity = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
 String stringToConvert = "strategy";
            byte[] theByteArray = stringToConvert.getBytes();

 secureRandom =  SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG").setSeed(theByteArray);

  tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
            tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getAddress();
                 //   Account();
                }
            });

}



    private void getAddress(){

        try {


            ECKey eck = new ECKey(provider , secureRandom);
            //new ECKey(Security.getProvider("EC"), new SecureRandom());
            Log.i(TAG , "Private key: " + Hex.toHexString(eck.getPrivKeyBytes()));
            Log.i(TAG , "Public key: " + Hex.toHexString(eck.getPubKey()));
            Log.i(TAG , "Address: " + ("0x" + Hex.toHexString(ECKey.computeAddress(eck.getPubKey()))));

            tv.setText(("0x" + Hex.toHexString(ECKey.computeAddress(eck.getPubKey()))));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG + "Exception = ", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Once you generated a key with `new ECKey()` you have to save it, otherwise you are going to generate new key every time. The behaviour you are describing is correct. Save the private key somewhere and then reuse it.

Comment: I am going to compile keystore package from`geth` for Android in a few weeks more, for an ethereum wallet we are going to release for android,  if you are interested in getting this code let me know.

Comment: How are you seeding `secureRandom`? Are you using the same seed each time? Using the same `SecureRandom` object repeatedly will generate different random numbers each time, but you should be able to call `.setSeed(...)` with some fixed value to get the same random numbers each time.

Comment: @smarx I converted seeds to bytearray than .setSeed(...) and used same object every click.Yet I found differen result everytime in an log.

Comment: @Nulik Sure....

Comment: To clarify, you're calling `setSeed` on each click, right? It might be easier to share your code rather than try to describe it.